# Mercurial: How to set it up on my own server?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I've got a server and I want to use Mercurial to coordinate a project. Can I just make a repo, put it on the server, and have everyone else clone it, then push/pull from it? Is there some way to password protect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The wiki has a good [breakdown](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) on the various mechanisms.  hgweb and hgwebdir (which I've used) are probably the simplest.  push is off by default, but can be [enabled](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#push).  They're simple Python scripts that can use Apache for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many people you have using the repository, you can just use a network share to push and pull from (eg: `\\myserver\repositories\myproject\`).  We have been doing this internally for some time with no issues, however we only have 3 people who ever access the repositories.  If you have more then you may consider doing what [Matthew Flaschen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042568/mercurial-how-to-set-it-up-on-my-own-server/3042584#3042584) says and use a [publishing method](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories).